# How to set the scale type programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set the scale type for an image through the `onBindViewHolder` method because the image looks way too stretched.  I had to comment out the last comment because I don't know how to use the `imageView.scaleType` method.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.view?.movie_poster?.setImageResource(R.drawable.beauty_and_the_beast_ver3)
    holder.view?.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
}
```

I'm a beginner developer trying to learn Android with Kotlin.

[image: This is the image]

And this is what I'm getting on the emulator:

[image]

Comment: Ideally your actual image should be in the same aspect ratio where you want to display it. It looks stretched because your image & display ratio doesn't match. You can try to use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your xml or apply it programmatically & see if that works for you. `centerCrop` will crop the area as per the image-view's height width from the center of the image so it won't look streched

Comment: and yeah, programatically `holder.view?.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`

Comment: Thank you @SandipSoni but now, only the top-right quarter of the image is shown.  I think that the image is too big for the radio.  What is the allowed image size?  My recyclerview has a gridlayout with 3 columns.

Comment: There is no such thing like allowed image size. For example, if your image is of vertical rectangle ratio & your imageview is of square ration, then it won't fit ever. You either need to make your actual image of square ration or you need to change your `ImageView` to rectangle ratio by specifying it's height & width accordingly. Or you can use the `scaleType` & try the various options like `centerInside`, `fitXy`,`centerCrop` & see which looks the best.

Comment: `FIT_CENTER` works but what it then does is put a giant white bar between each row.

Comment: could you show the actual image & your ImageView where you are setting it?

Comment: @SandipSoni check the edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168338/discussion-between-sandip-soni-and-onur-ozbek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Screenshot you uploaded & the code you posted in chat, below are the problem of yours:

- You have set the height of `RecyclerView` `list_item` to `match_parent` which is wrong. Make it `wrap_content`
- You had put the image you were testing in the `drawable` folder which was too big for the ImageView height you were expecting in `GridView`. So you need to put it in `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder to make it a bit smaller.
- You need to set the height of `ImageView` to some fixed dps like `200dp` in order to prevent the weird looking grids when you actually load the images from API which might have different resolutions.
- And in the end, to **hide** the improper `ImageView` height and actual drawable image's height, you need to add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to the `ImageView` in `list_item.xml` (Ofcourse, when loading images from API, you'll need to make sure that the images from server comes in same aspect ratio as you won't to display it to avoid using `scaleType`)